# Wordpress Categories as a Grid

Tags: plugins, categories

I like to create a Grid on my Homepage based on my Wordpress-Categories.

I also would like to filter them.

On the attached image, you can see what i mean.

[image]

Which Plugins do i need?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Post Category Image With Grid and Slider](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-category-image-with-grid-and-slider/) plugin. It allows you to upload and display category image in grid. It's really easy to use. After activating the plugin, go to **Category Image** and select **Categories.** Here, you will find all the options for uploading and displaying the images in grid.